# Error Mysql: Subquery returns more than 1 row MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need help. i know that the column i am creating has more than 1 row, but i do not know how to resolve it. Somebody have an idea?

```
select productid,pb.pricebookid,(select bookname 
                             from vtiger_pricebook p 
                             inner join vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
                                    on p.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
                             where pbp.pricebookid = '299182') Wx
from vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
join vtiger_pricebook pb
ON pb.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
```

[image]

What i really expect is this
[image]

Comment: `SELECT` defines what to show in each row (i.e. 1 row).  So if you use sub-query in `SELECT` make sure it return no more than 1 row.

Comment: Depend upon what you want. You can use group_concat to see all the values comma separated from your sub query. Or may be limit 1 if you want one value

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Just run the subquery alone and check the results. Which one do you need for the outer query? Update the query until you just get one record. If it does return just one row, it might be just by chance and may change in the future, so the query must be written in such a way that it can return only one row.

Comment: runing the subquery alone just return more than 1 row, and what i want it is to list all the in the wx name i give for the column. This is the matter

Comment: @forpas i just edited my question and put some image to be more clear

Comment: So you expect in the results a column `listprice` which is nowhere to be found. Post sample data of **all** the tables involved and expected results in **text** format and not images and explain what you want. *What i really expect is this* is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Guy thanks to help but i have found how to resolve myself. i just use my subquery after WHERE Clause.

So, this is the answer:

```
SELECT productid,pb.pricebookid, listprice
FOM vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
join vtiger_pricebook pb
ON pb.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
WHERE pb.bookname IN (select listprice from vtiger_pricebook p inner join vtiger_pricebookproductrel pbp
ON p.pricebookid = pbp.pricebookid
WHERE pbp.pricebookid = '299182')
```

> WHERE pb.bookname IN(SUBQUERY HERE)

Comment: `WHERE pb.bookname IN (select listprice`????? That makes NO sense at all. How comes a book name matches a list price? I guess the subquery is `(select bookname...`, right? In any case, matching like this by book name looks like a bad idea. You should use unique identifiers, like `productid`.